# Can domain hacks (ex .lr, .pt) be seized if the intended use is outside of country policy?

Tags: dns, website, domain

I wanted to register a url, it's either going to end in **.lr** or **.pt** (I haven't decided.)

I was apprehensive that since my website has no intent in promoting or representing **Libera - .lr** (I don't even know where this is on a map) it may get taken down.

**.lr** domains are expensive ($150/each on 101domain.com) so I wanted to make sure that before I purchase one, as long as I have paid for it, the domain won't be confiscated.  I notice the http://www.tumb.lr domain hack no longer resolves, so I was concerned that it got taken down - potentially for violating policy of not being a website about Liberia.

**See Also**

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.lr
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.pt
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: Whoever voted to close this, can you suggest a stackexchange site that is more fitting for my question?

Comment: This is nonense :) You can buy any domain you like and host your material. Recently .co came out, I read it stood for .company - turns out it's for columbia - However, we kept it and have nothing to do with Columbia and there are no problems

Comment: I don't think there's a [se] on legality. Plus, it varies across different regions

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are allowed to register domains depends on the rules that the registrar has set up for this.

Some country registrars do not allow outsiders; for example, [Liberia Domain Registration](http://psg.com/dns/lr/) says:

> Registrations must be from organizations with a real presence in the country and with a demonstrable intent to use the domain name on a regular basis on the internet.

Other registrars are happy to accept money from everyone, but for [`.pt`](https://www.dns.pt/), this is true only under `.com.pt`.